# Why did 'reset_index(drop=True)' function unwantedly remove column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe named **data_match**. It contains columns '_worker_id', '_unit_id', and 'caption'. (Please see attached screenshot for some of the rows in this dataframe)

[image]

Let's say the index column is not in ascending order (I want the index to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4...n) and I want it to be in ascending order. So I ran the following function attempting to reset the index column:

```
data_match=data_match.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I was able to get the function to return the correct output in my computer using Python 3.6. However, when my coworker ran that function in his computer using Python 3.6, the '_worker_id' column got removed.

Is this due to the `(drop=True)` clause next to `reset_index`? But I didn't know why it worked in my computer and not in my coworker's computer. Can anybody advise?

Comment: reset_index(drop=True) will definitely work the same on your computer and your coworker's computer if both are running Python 3.6. And it won't drop a random column.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the saying goes, "What happens in your interpreter stays in your
interpreter".  It's impossible to explain the discrepancy without seeing the
full history of commands entered into both Python interactive sessions.

However, it is possible to venture a guess:

[`df.reset_index(drop=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
drops the current index of the DataFrame and replaces it with an index of
increasing integers. It never drops columns.

So, in your interactive session, `_worker_id` was a column.  In your co-worker's
interactive session, `_worker_id` must have been an index level.

The visual difference can be somewhat subtle. For example, below, `df` has a
`_worker_id` column while `df2` has a `_worker_id` index level:

```
In [190]: df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3], '_worker_id':list('ABC')}); df
Out[190]: 
  _worker_id  foo
0          A    1
1          B    2
2          C    3

In [191]: df2 = df.set_index('_worker_id', append=True); df2
Out[191]: 
              foo
  _worker_id     
0 A             1
1 B             2
2 C             3
```

Notice that the name `_worker_id` appears one line below `foo` when it is an
index level, and on the same line as `foo` when it is a column. That is the only
visual clue you get when looking at the `str` or `repr` of a DataFrame.

So to repeat: When `_worker_index` is a column, the column is unaffected by
`df.reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
In [194]: df.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[194]: 
  _worker_id  foo
0          A    1
1          B    2
2          C    3
```

But `_worker_index` is dropped when it is part of the index:

```
In [195]: df2.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[195]: 
   foo
0    1
1    2
2    3
```

Comment: Thanks, @unutbu! Really appreciate your answer. I had relayed your feedback to my coworker and he said that's exactly what happened, that the '_worker_id' column became an index column instead of data frame column before he ran the 'reset_index(drop=True)' function. So he must've done something earlier in the script that caused the '_worker_id' to become an index column.                                              
 Is there a way that we could force Python to not change a data frame column to index column?

Comment: There is more than one way column values could become part of an index. The `set_index`, `pivot`, `pivot_table`, `groupby` DataFrame methods can all have this effect. There is no way to prevent column values from moving to the index if you are using these methods -- after all, that's the intended effect! However, after the fact, you can move the index level back to a column by calling `df.reset_index(drop=False)`.