# Python3 Pandas - TypeError: an integer is required in merge of hash columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hash, merge

Two dataframes have a **hash** column that is the result of:

```
df['hash'] = df_without.apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis = 1)
```

When the **dtypes** of both dataframes are printed, it says:

```
0     object
1     object
2     object
3     object
4     object
5     object
6     object
7     object
8     object
9     object
10    object
11    object
12    object
13    object
14    object
15    object
16    object
dtype: object

0     object
1     object
2     object
3     object
4     object
5     object
6     object
7     object
8     object
9     object
10    object
11    object
12    object
13    object
14    object
15    object
16    object
dtype: object
```

So when I want the two dataframes to be merged by the **hash** column, I do this:

```
 df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on=['hash'], right_on = ['hash'])
```

But I get the error:

```
 TypeError: an integer is required
 KeyError: 'hash'
```

I tried to parse the column to **String** like this:

```
 df['hash'] = df['hash'].astype(str)
```

But nothing changes. Should I force to parse it to Integer?

Comment: Try `df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='hash', right_on = 'hash')`

Comment: @AzfarFaizan it prompts the same error.

Comment: The dtypes output you posted shows that neither `df1` nor `df2` have a column named `hash`. This is why `pd.merge` would raise a `KeyError` if you merge on `'hash'`.

Comment: @unutbu When I print the df1 and df2 dataframes it shows the 'hash' columns. Is there a way to a column have values without being a column?

Comment: If `hash` were an index level then its labels might appear like a column of values, except that the name `hash` would appear [one line below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620566/190597) the column names. `df1.columns.tolist()` will show you all the column names in `df1`. While `df1.index.names` will show you the names of the index level(s).